# How to log quantities of IP traffic by src/dst (and port for UDP & TCP)?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, traffic, statistics

How can I log quantities of IP traffic by src/dst (and port for UDP & TCP)?

For each interval (probably each hour) I would like to see something like:

```
proto, src, dst, packets, octets
ICMP, 192.168.1.3, 2.3.4.5, 34, 483
TCP, 192.168.1.3:34821, 2.3.4.5:80, 123, 23408
TCP, 192.168.1.3:33812, 5.6.7.8:22, 201, 2039
TCP, 192.168.1.3:53, 1.1.1.1:53, 23, 3400
UDP, 192.168.1.3:53, 1.1.1.1:53, 323, 23403
```

For a gateway/router box, I expect thousands of lines each hour.

I know that iptables can count traffic, but as far as I have understood you need to know the addresses and ports before you start counting.

Is there a commonly used solution to counting *all* IP traffic?

(I am looking for a low-level tool/technique, not a function of a network management suite.)

Comment: conntrack do that. just set net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1 with sysctl

Comment: @ibrahim Thanks, could you turn that into an answer?  Perhaps explain how you would get the information out of conntrack, and how you would zero the conntrack counters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get byte and packet counts from conntrack.

To enable counters, set accounting

```
#sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1
```

Then you will see conntrack ouput like this

```
#conntrack -L
tcp      6 431971 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.0.156 dst=192.168.0.1 sport=53474 dport=443 packets=11 bytes=1945 src=192.168.0.1 dst=192.168.0.156 sport=443 dport=53474 packets=12 bytes=5238 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```

You can zero counters with this command

```
#conntrack -L -z
```

Note that these counters are connection based. Conntrack entry will be removed once connection closed.

Check man page for more information

```
#man conntrack
```

Comment: Do conntrack counters survive for any length of time after the connection is closed?  If not, even running "conntrack -L" *every minute* will miss short-lived connections.

Comment: yes. you will lost data one the connection closed. maybe you can parse output of "conntrack -E" stream

Comment: Thanks, though I'll look at how `conntrack -E` gets its data, rather than parsing a format which might change.

Comment: conntrack gather informations from nf_conntrack kernel module. If you are interested, you can write your own simple module to gather data you want. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426783/netfilter-kernel-module-to-intercept-packets-and-log-them